# Why does Prisma Client $queryRaw on the server return data in this format?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

Why Prisma Client $queryRaw On Server return data like this?

```
[
  {
    "id": {
      "prisma__type": "int",
      "prisma__value": 73
    },
    "region": {
      "prisma__type": "string",
      "prisma__value": ""
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```